# Terrible performance during animation playback

Tags: animation, performance

I'm struggling to understand why is performance so bad when I'm editing rig controls or whenever I start the animation playback. My scene is a mannequin character exported from the Unreal Engine 5. I checked the tris count and it's almost 100k which isn't really that much. Then whenever I perform any of the above mentioned actions the FPS drop to range between 12 and 15 which I consider bad.

My specs:
RTX 4070
Ryzen 7 3700X

I have tried looking through different settings inside preferences but no luck there. I also tried installing different Blender versions so I tested this on Blender 3.3, 3.4 and most recent 3.5, all of them act exactly same.

Does anyone have an idea what could be happening here? Cheers for any help!

Comment: that doesn't sound normal indeed, could you do `file > external data > pack all into .blend file`, then `file > save as` : enable compress in sidebar and save a copy of your file, then upload it somewhere like [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here with us so that we can dig in?

Comment: Sure thing, file is too big for blend-exchange but I uploaded it to my mega cloud, you can download it here: https://mega.nz/file/HschGJqB#NgnIQTqSl1p6K8aclIjlR090tJBSmL33jMdsJO1XtoM

Let me know if it's all right and nothing is missing! Thanks for checking this out

Comment: I checked the file, and I'm pretty sure there isn't any issue there. So I'd advise you to first try to make a clean reinstallation of your graphics driver, and try again. If this doesn't work, then go to the menu `Help > Report A Bug` and send a bug report with the pre-filled instructions, and send the file there too. Hopefully the devs will either find out what's going on, and make a fix for it if need be.

Comment: Right, so I was afraid it might be an issue on my side. I have recently performed clean driver installation as I was switching from RTX 2070 to 4070 and figured this might be the issue. I'll report the bug. Thanks for your help!